# Keep getting 422 unprocessable entity

Tags: node.js, reactjs, http

Below is my code I keep getting error that it is unprocessable i looked it up and it said
to assign headers to content-type : "application/json" and i am still getting the errors.

```
export async function action({ request, params }) {
  const data = await request.formData();
  const eventData = {
    title: data.get("title"),
    Image: data.get("image"),
    date: data.get("date"),
    description: data.get("description"),
  };
  console.log(JSON.stringify(eventData));
  const stringData = JSON.stringify(eventData);
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/events", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: stringData,
  });
  console.log(response);
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw json({ message: "Could not save event" }, { status: 500 });
  }

  return redirect("/events");
}
```

it says server is expecting json and i have converted the data to json and still getting the error

Comment: Are you sure that the `Image` key in your request body should start with a capital `I`?

Comment: show the server part, client part seems good